Is there a way to use my cellular as an AP to boost the internet, ethernet, wifi, or first phones at home?
I am limited in my knowledge and terminology so in warehouses you have APs access points, connected to IDFs, which in turn are connected to the MDF which is basically the main control room receiving and sending info to technicians at headquarters for troubleshooting, planning and development remotely. When the system is active it is a closed loop system until fiber cords are disconnected. I am asking if I can emulate this setup between my electronics to boost signal and speed at home as well as be able to remotely troubleshoot from my cell away from home.

First, this is a hardware question, and really doesn't belong  here. Second, your question is unclear. Do you need a WiFi range extender? That is not a cell phone.

You won’t be able to boost a signal. You can connect to the signal with a device which generates a new signal. This is how WiFi extender work. 4G/5G extenders work by connecting to the internet and generating a compatible signal for the provider network

Not with the approaches you are looking at, no.
I am not sure that IDF and MDF's are standard terms relating to WIFI and networking (maybe you are talking about some kind of Internal Distribution feed and Master Distribution feed - but that would be arbitrary verbage within your org).   Regardless, this does not really apply to consumer or prosumer networks.
It is also uncertain what you mean by a "closed loop system".  WIFI and Ethernet networks should not be "closed loop" in as much as any loops will cause packet switching issues unless/until resolved or supressed by an enterprise grade switch.
In order to boost your connectivity at home there are a few approaches - You can use a mesh technology and/or Repeaters (both of these are inefficient from a bandwidth POV, so I use them sparingly).  You can also wire up multiple AP's to switches to extend your range. There are no doubt many solutions here - Ubiquity is fairly prosumer and can get you a large part of the way where you want to go.
As far as remotely monitoring your network, you will need external connectivity or an external mechanism relaying and controlling your network.  This is relatively complex to set up as you are working at a different level in the network.      For local monitoring and control, a Ubiquity network + A Ubiquity Cloud Key can get you a good part of the way there.  You would still need to get remote connectivity to your cloud key.
